# entityManagerFactory NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot

I'm doing simple api with Spring Boot and embeeded database and it's hits me an

> NoClassDefFoundError. : Error creating bean with name
>   'entityManagerFactory'

Maybe you know which dependency I should include to my pom.xml.
Maven project.
here is what i have:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory'
>   parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in
>   class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory
>   method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError has javadocs. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html  a class or a dependency of that class is not in the CLASSPATH. Nothing (explicitly) to do with the JPA or anything, just basic Java

Answer (score 1):

`hibernate-core` and `hibernate-entitymanager` are being transitively included via `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`

**Edited:** Could you first try removing you local `.m2/repository`? Sometime it gets corrupted.

`rm -rf ~/.m2/repository`

Could you include which `Spring Boot` version are you using `pom.xml` content.

Could you also include you data source and JPA properties?

Comment: I can't believe that removing .m2 helped, but it did. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Make sure none of your dependencies (except `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`) have inclusive dependency to `hibernate-core`. Otherwise libraries may get clashed.

**2)** You may also need to add this artifact:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Version should be inferred.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm real noob at it, so my question is how I can check if my dependencies have inclusive dependency to hibernate-core?

Comment: If you use Eclipse, there an option to flat-view all the deps also the inclusive ones on a pom.xml file