# Encountered exception while deploying to tomcat locally

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, catalina

I'm trying to deploy on tomcat locally but the logs file doesn't give any clear errors, I'm using Spring boot application with Maven.

I have removed javax.servlet dependency and set my server.servlet.contextPath=/EServicesPortal in properties file and I set Tomcat home file in setting and deploy a new war file but still getting the same error.

```
    2020-01-12 11:35:34.782 ERROR 3616 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.findConstructorBindingAnnotatedConstructor(ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.java:62) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.getBindConstructor(ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.java:48) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBean$BindMethod.forType(ConfigurationPropertiesBean.java:311) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.validate(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.java:63) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.java:45) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:286) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:174) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:152) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:132) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:92) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172) [spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154) [catalina.jar:8.5.50]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:8.5.50]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743) [catalina.jar:8.5.50]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719) [catalina.jar:8.5.50]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705) [catalina.jar:8.5.50]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:970) [catalina.jar:8.5.50]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1841) [catalina.jar:8.5.50]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_231]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_231]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_231]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_231]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_231]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1358) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.50]
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.50]
        ... 32 common frames omitted

12-Jan-2020 11:35:34.785 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
        org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/E-Services-Portal-2.2.2.RELEASE]]
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:970)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1841)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager
                at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
                at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
                at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.findConstructorBindingAnnotatedConstructor(ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.java:62)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.getBindConstructor(ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.java:48)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBean$BindMethod.forType(ConfigurationPropertiesBean.java:311)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.validate(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.java:63)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.java:45)
                at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:286)
                at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:174)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:152)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:132)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:92)
                at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                ... 10 more
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1358)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
                ... 32 more
12-Jan-2020 11:35:34.785 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [C:\Users\Desktop\apache-tomcat-8.5.50-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.50\webapps\E-Services-Portal-2.2.2.RELEASE.war]
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/E-Services-Portal-2.2.2.RELEASE]]
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:747)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:970)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1841)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
12-Jan-2020 11:35:34.785 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\Users\Desktop\apache-tomcat-8.5.50-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.50\webapps\E-Services-Portal-2.2.2.RELEASE.war] has finished in [8,791] ms
12-Jan-2020 11:35:34.785 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\Desktop\apache-tomcat-8.5.50-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.50\webapps\docs]
```

**UPDATE:** 
As requested this is current POM file and I have added hibernate dependency then the error got changed ( I have updated the error ) :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>




<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-2-starter</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.fworks</groupId>
        <artifactId>simplerestdoc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>




<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
    </repository>

</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <webappDirectory>/sample/servlet/container/deploy/directory</webappDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48194602/entitymanagerfactory-noclassdeffounderror]

Comment: @Vishal they suggested to use hibernate and I don't have DB to use it

Comment: Please add the content of the pom.xml file please

Comment: If you're not using those features (database, JPA), configure Spring Boot not to use them. You can use the [project builder](https://start.spring.io/) to configure only the things you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause of error here is the dependency version mismatch. Please use the starter dependencies of spring boot to avoid such mismatches. Actually, it is one of the motive behind the creation of spring-boot.

> Provide opinionated 'starter' dependencies to simplify your build configuration

1. Declare spring-boot-starter-parent as parent dependency with required version.
2. Declare starter dependencies without versions. (parent dependency uses correct versions)

for example,

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thanks noted ! but it didn't solve this error ( `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager
` )

Comment: plz share your updated pom using the starter dependencies.

Comment: You still have few unnecessary dependency declarations which already are included in starter dependencies with their correct versions. For starters, just try commenting out `spring-security-oauth2-client` which is already included in starter oath2 client dependency with correct version 5.2.1. (this should resolve your exception error)
Similarly, there are few other dependencies which are included in starter dependencies. Identify them by commenting them out and using `mvn dependency:tree` to check if they are still loaded in mvn tree from the starter dependencies.

Comment: Thanks ! I have change the oath2 client version to 5.2.1 but i'm getting this error ( `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client:pom:5.2.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced`

Comment: the last version on Spring Boot OAuth2/OpenID Connect Client Starter is 2.2.2 not 5.2.1

Comment: the starter version is 2.2.2. The starter contains all the required dependencies in their correct version. like. `spring-security-oauth2-client:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE`. Please remove declaration of `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>` and it should fix the error.